# Styling OL-LI Numbers Differently Than LI Text

Tags: html, css, list

I need to style <ol> item numbers differently than the <ol><li> text itself. There have been questions asked similar to this, but I didn't see a solution.

Example:

```css
ol[lang] li:before {
  font-style: normal !important
}

* [lang] {
  font-style: italic
}
```

```html
<ol lang="la">
  <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
  <li>Consectetur Adipiscing Elit</li>
  <li>Aenean Porta Neque Sem</li>
</ol>
```

The Latin text is italicized, as expected, but the list item numbers (1,2,3) are **also** italicized, which is **not** what I need. Firefox, Chrome & Edge all render it like this.

Can separate styling for list item numbers be done in CSS without having to insert a span/style inside each <li>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for that method to actually work, you need remove the default numbers and display custom numbers using pseudo elements.

In the example below, the numbers are added though the `content` property on the `:before` pseudo elements. [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) are used to increment the value accordingly.

```css
ol[lang] {
  list-style: none;
}
ol[lang] li {
  counter-increment: number;
  font-style: italic;
}
ol[lang] li:before {
  content: counter(number) '. ';
  font-style: normal;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ol lang="la">
  <li>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</li>
  <li>Consectetur Adipiscing Elit</li>
  <li>Aenean Porta Neque Sem</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: All I can say is : Wow. It works. Would never have guessed that solution in a million parsecs. Thanks for the quick assist, Josh!